# Div taking up space where it isn't located

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on making a game of memory. I can't figure out why when I remove a class that has display as none, it moves the parent element div down. If I try to counter that by on the same click function, adding a class that moves it 125px up, it still leaves a space under it. It is removing a class from the span inside the parent div. To my knowledge, position being set to absolute isn't an option because of this applying to every single div. Any further suggestions past a fix are welcome.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o0xmcapx/9/

```
$('.card').click(function(){
  $(this).find("span").toggleClass( "cardText" );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `display:inline-block` your `card` aligns to baseline vertically....

...so use `vertical-align:top` to the `card` class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log('lol');
  var items = [
    "PSotato",
    "Tomato",
    "Strawberry",
    "Pencil",
    "Blueberry",
    "Raspberry",
    "Lettuce",
    "Steak"
  ];
  items = shuffle(items)
  //console.log(items);

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="card"/>').html('<span class="cardText">' + items[i] + '</span>').appendTo('.board');
  };

  items = shuffle(items);

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="card"/>').html('<span class="cardText">' + items[i] + '</span>').appendTo('.board');
  };
  $('.card').click(function() {
    $(this).find("span").toggleClass("cardText");
  });
});
```

```css
.board {
  height: 630px;
  width: 630px;
  background-color: #DAD6D6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -315px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 157.5px;
}

.card {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 14.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #B6455F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cardText {
  display: none;
}

.altCardText {
  position: relative;
  top: -125px;
}

.notHidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="board"></div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/o0xmcapx/18/)**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this has something to do with this: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins. The weird thing is that the span in your code doesn't have margins or padding.

Regardless, here are a few of the many options:

- Change `.cardText` to have `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none`.
- Add `overflow: auto` to `.card`
- Add flex to `.board` (if you do this you could remove `display: inline-block` on `.card`):

```css
.board {
  ...
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```